# First lowercase the text then capitalize it. Is it possible with CSS?

Tags: css

First lowercase the text then capitalize it. Is it possible with CSS?

Edit: Example:
`HELLO WORLD` -> `Hello World`

Edit2: I have a list of countries which are all uppercase, like `UNITED KINGDOM`, I have to make it look like `United Kingdom`.

Comment: Do You Mean Make It Like This Comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep:

```
.className {
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function capitalize(s){
    return s.toLowerCase().replace( /\b./g, function(a){ return a.toUpperCase(); } );
};

capitalize('this IS THE wOrst string eVeR');
```

Stolen from here:
[Capitalize words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string/2332821#2332821)

Comment: "ThIs is some RANDOM text!" becomes "ThIs Is Some RANDOM Text!"... I believe he wants it to become "This Is Some Random Text!" if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done if the text inside the element is only on one line, using the `::first-line` pseudo-element:

```
<h3>HELLO WORLD</h3>
<style>
    h3 {
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }

    h3::first-line {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I not have permission to comment, so I'll write my experience as an answer.

I have a problem with accentuated chars, solved  puting '^' in the begin of regex and iterate each word of the text.

'^' indicates to match only the first char of word.

```
function captalize(s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replace( /^\b./g, function(a){ return a.toUpperCase(); } );
}

var words = exampleText.split(" ");

jQuery.each(words, function(index, value) {
       var w = capitalize(value);
       exampleText.append(w).append(" ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was to apply `.toLocaleLowerCase()` in Javascript and then use the CSS `text-transform: capitalize;`.

This way, all the first letters are uppercase. I wish we could achieve that with pure CSS only.

Comment: But the asker wanted to achieve this with pure CSS, without JavaScript.

Comment: That’s why I added “ I wish we could achieve that with pure CSS only.” :)