# Lower case all then capitalize - pure CSS

Tags: capitalize, css

I saw this topic here: [First lowercase the text then capitalize it. Is it possible with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280015/first-lowercase-the-text-then-capitalize-it-is-it-possible-with-css)

But it wasn't pure CSS. I have a div that contains this text:

```
<div>
RaWr rAwR
</div>
```

I want to use css to make it look like "Rawr Rawr". Cut if I just to text-transform capitalize it makes it "RaWr RAwR", the already uppercase letters remain upper case. So I need to lower case it all first then capitalize, is the solution to wrap it in a div?

I tried wrapping it in another div but it didnt work:

```
<style>
    #test3 { text-transform: lowercase; }
    #test3 div { text-transform: capitalize; }
</style>

<div id="test3"><div>RaWr rAwR</div></div>
```

Comment: As the comments in your linked question state, there is no way of doing this with pure CSS. You will need to use Javascript.

Comment: yep i tried it man, i was wondering if there was any new ways, bisdato gave intresting solution below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sadly, you cannot do this with pure CSS. For now your best hope is to either rewrite text to avoid medial/final capitals or use JavaScript. (Yes, my eyes are rolling too.)

Your suggested approach doesn't work because only one `text-transform` property value applies to an element at a time. When you specify something like…

```css
#parent { text-transform: lowercase; }
#parent #child { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

…the value of `text-transform` on the child element is now `capitalize`, and nothing else. This is the only transformation applied to that element.

There is a draft proposal to allow authors to [define custom mapping tables with an `@text-transform` rule](http://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/at-text-transform#the-scope-descriptor), but as it stands I doubt it would work for this scenario. The problem is that the [`scope` descriptor](http://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/at-text-transform#the-scope-descriptor) (where in a word the transformation applies) only takes one value—you could define a transformation on the whole word or some combination of the start, end or middle parts of a word, but it's not obvious if you could have different transformations for each part.

This seems to be acknowledged in **Issue 8** on the wiki draft proposal, and [multiple transforms were discussed a couple of years back on www-style](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Dec/0418.html). In that thread it is suggested that only a single `text-transform` value should be allowed on an element, and that combining should be done in the `@text-transform` rule; however, the draft spec notes:

> If the text-transforms referred to have a different scope than the scope specified
>   in the text-transform that refers to them, they apply at the intersection of the
>   two scopes.

So a rule like this **wouldn't work:**

```css
@text-transform lowercase-then-capitalize {
    transformation: lowercase, "a-z" to "A-Z" single;
    scope: initial;
}
```

I can see three obvious solutions:

1. allow multiple `scope` values to be specified in the `@text-transform` rule;
2. add a descriptor to inherit a previous transformation *without* overriding its scope value; or
3. permit multiple `text-transform` values for a selector.

[The www-style mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/) might be a good place to take this if you ever want to see a pure CSS solution to this question.

Comment: Sincere thank you for this extremely great answer! I now know what to do when they do implement it. Thanks much! I also now know what the current limitations are.

Answer (score 25):

This should do it when you have the single words in different div's

```
#test3 { text-transform: lowercase; }

#test3::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }


<div id="test3">haLLo</div>
```

Comment: Only works for the first letter though `Rawr rawr` not `Rawr Rawr`.

Comment: I don't think it will work if there are multiple words inside div

Comment: Ah this is nice! At least it gets it if it has one word. No need for a wrap on this one either I like it. Ill keep this one in mind for future but it wont help me right now :( Still +1

Comment: This helped me in my case, thanks!

Comment: it should be '#test3::first-letter {'

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: I agree this answer is more useful than the accepted answer, but it also doesn't quite answer the question. As Noitidart mentions this will only work if there's only 1 word in the element.

Answer (score 1):

You are using nested div,

So `#test3 { text-transform: lowercase; }` is applied for Parent `div` so it applies for Both Parent and Child Divs

when you override the `#test3 div { text-transform: capitalize; }` to the Child Div the first style `text-transform: lowercase;` is ignored

Comment: ah yeah it doesnt work :( i was hoping for a non nesting solution

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, until CSS 3 there is no way to do this in pure CSS way, as per [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#transforming) document there are only 5 possible values to `text-transform` and none of them will solve this requirement!

But in future there might be provision for custom rule for text transform similar to [`Counter Sytle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#CSS-COUNTER-STYLES-3)

Comment: _till CSS-3_? What can CSS 3 do?

Comment: as mentioned in updated answer there might be provision which will allow us to custom define `text-transform` rules