# CSS from uppercase to capitalize

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to transform my uppercase text in capitalize text in the html page.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of parameterStruct">
  <span class="sideBar-text" style="font-size: 12px"> 
    {{item.description}}
  </span>
</ng-container>
```

From *item.description* I get an uppercase text. Is there a way to use a css property in order to have a capitalize text?

Comment: `Is There A Way To Use A Css Property In Order To Have A Capitalize Text?` what does this mean ?

Comment: `style="text-transform: capitalize;"`

Comment: Short answer: no, this cannot be done in pure CSS, you will need JS to achieve this. Long answer: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21829777/540725

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is capitalize won't lowercase other characters from an uppercase text. What you can do is

```
.sideBar-text{
    text-transform : lowercase;
}

.sideBar-text:first-letter{
    text-transform : uppercase;
}
```

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d2c9fe2e136efefbdb59a9ae4ee4e689

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: This works only if its one word per html-element

Comment: I don't get it : check this link, I think it's a two words HTML ;) https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d2c9fe2e136efefbdb59a9ae4ee4e689

Comment: Yes. "world" is lowercase. Capitalize would mean to output "Hello World". Not sure tough if this is really what is intended by GigiProve, but if not the question should be edited accordingly

Comment: Oh, right, depends on what he wants ! In my head it was clear he only wanted the first letter =D What about angular lowercase pipe combined with CSS capitalize then ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried capitalize?

```
.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

<span class="sideBar-text capitalize" style="font-size: 12px"> 
  {{item.description}}
</span>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use css `text-transform: capitalize;` to make text to Upper case.

More description can be found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform