# Text lowercase after capitalization is possible?

Tags: html, css, angular

My database give mixed font styles, for Example:

> " Hi THis is TEST teXT "

I want to capitalization this type of fonts. I found a way, first using lowercase and then `::first-letter` to be capitalized. This give the first letter only capital.

But I want capitalization in every first word, is there any way?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe Please refer

Comment: I want only in style css, without using angular.

Comment: "But i want capitalization in every first word" .. First word or first letter on each word??

Comment: Yes its possible in css.. You can add this for example, h5 {text-transform: lowercase;}

Comment: What means every first word? Of sentences? Look for .!? And then the next letter (index) and then capitalize it. It’s kinda manual work.

Comment: @manikandan lowercase ok, then how capitalization is possible.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe how you would like your sample " Hi THis is TEST teXT " to be output, as it isn't clear from your wording.

Comment: Ok @Nikolaus, but manual work not possible in big projects right.

Comment: @Sahin Yes that is also possible.. but if the letter is in fully uppercase its not possible to covert that word to capitalize..

Comment: @Manikandan2811 not upper case mixed uppercase also not possible, i tried.

Comment: `text-transform:capitalize ` should do the trick

Comment: @Sahin yes ofcourse too..

Comment: Manikandan2811 and Thomas Byy there is no way using this text-transform:capitalize  to convert, because these are database values and mixed fonts, like capital and small

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First lowercase the text then capitalize it. Is it possible with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280015/first-lowercase-the-text-then-capitalize-it-is-it-possible-with-css)

Comment: This is imposible using pure CSS to transform text to lowercase then capitalize it

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.c {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h2>text-transform: capitalize:</h2>
<div class="c">Hi THis is TEST teXT</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this.

Comment: it is not fixed my scenario.

Comment: @Sahin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827377/lower-case-all-then-capitalize-pure-css There is no solution with css , Try with js

Comment: Not working, i already checked.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
function titleCase(str) {
var splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
   // You do not need to check if i is larger than splitStr length, as your for does 
       that for you
   // Assign it back to the array
    splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);     
}
// Directly return the joined string
return splitStr.join(' '); 
}

document.write(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Please see [Capitalize First Letter Of Each Word In A String - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589197/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-javascript/32589256)

Comment: no java scripts only css

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you strictly want to do it in style.css file:

```
selector{
text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Another option is :

```
{{ textToBeConverted | uppercase }}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Using css, is possible ? Please understand the scenario

Comment: Oh I get it. Your data is in mixed form.  Why don't you use the second option using pipe {{ textToBeConverted | uppercase }}

Comment: Our side is large number of data, so can't using angular functions, bit slow, and next reason is we dont go with dev side, using client side is better to formatting.

Comment: Honestly it isn't so slow that it would make a difference to the user. The data rendered would not take hefty amount of time.I work with huge data set and using pipes never made a problem.

Comment: Ohh ok, but we have some issues regarding this, thats why.

Comment: Okay. Has to be your call after all. Good day !

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a inbuilt pipe for this

```
{{name | titlecase}}
```

link

https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe

Comment: Using angular this is a way i know, but using css i want

Comment: oh ok let me check

Answer (score 0):

What you want is **impossible using pure CSS**. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827377/lower-case-all-then-capitalize-pure-css).

Alternative, you can use it with angular lowercase pipe and titlecase pipe:

```
{{ textToTransform | lowercase | titlecase }}
```

Comment: with your reference link, they posted "cant do this with pure CSS". but using angular pipe will do right. i want to try using pure css, thats why i created a new ticked.