# how can I make the first letter of each word capitalized when each word is capitalized?( :first-letter is not working )

Tags: css

I am trying to assign a style to an element where its attribute `index=0`
The selector `:first-letter`  is not working.

How can do it the selector by attribute (in this case `[index='0']` )?

My desired output for the first element is:
**T**ext 0 **P**aragraph (red text)

```css
p[index='0']{
  color:red;
}

p[index='0']{
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

p[index='0']:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p index="0">TEXT 0 PARAGRAPH</p>
<p index="1">TEXT 1 PARAGRAPH</p>
<p index="2">TEXT 2 PARAGRAPH</p>
<p index="3">TEXT 3 PARAGRAPH</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lower case all then capitalize - pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827377/lower-case-all-then-capitalize-pure-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first-letter` only work on the first word. If your text is short you can use `:first-line`. Otherwise you need to use js to transform it

```
p[index='0']{
  color:red;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

p[index='0']:first-line{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: output is the first letter of the first word, I need the first letter of each word

Comment: "capitalize" transforms the first character of each word to uppercase @yavgz

Comment: if the text is capitalized from the beginning , it not works, I updated my code

Comment: Oke got it, I've updated the answer accordingly