# Regex for first element of word as Uppercase but in brackets should be Lowercase

Tags: javascript, regex, angular1.6

**I want to create regex which should work with  tag. Example code is as follows:**

```
<div class="numericGoalMetFooter ng-binding">
                    Total time(s)
</div>
```

If I use css text-transform: capitalize then output follows:

```
Total Time(S)
```

I want the text as follows:

```
Total Time(s)
```

Note :
"time(s)" comes dynamically from database. 
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: How about wrapping them in `spans` and capitalize only `Total Time`?

Comment: Is it an option to modify whatever supplies that text to just be correct?

Comment: Actually , Total time(s) comes dynamically from database.

Comment: So, is it an option to correct it in the database? If not, then that might be simpler than trying to do a postfix every time you get the value.

Comment: Can't you do it similar to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280015/first-lowercase-the-text-then-capitalize-it-is-it-possible-with-css and use another regex for the matching something like: `\b(?<!\().` with a lookbehind to ensure no bracket was seen before. You can see https://regex101.com/r/539CTL/1 for reference

Answer (score 0):

**As, I was using angularjs so I created custom filter and remove text css.**

*Angular custom filter:*

```
app.filter('capitalize', function() {
        return function(input) {
            return (!!input) ? input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
        }
    });
```

*Html:*

```
<div class="numericGoalMetUnit">
    Total {{challenge.unit  | capitalize}}
</div>
```