# Lowercase and then Capitalize first letter of each word with ONLY CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to lowercase all the letters of a line and then capitalize it.
I have tried the following code but it only works the last text-transform style:

```css
.lowercase{text-transform: lowercase}
.capitalize{text-transform: capitalize}
```

```html
<div class="lowercase">
  <span class="capitalize">SURNAME, name</span>
</div>
```

Comment: With only CSS, no. You'd need to do one or the other of the two operations via JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First lowercase the text then capitalize it. Is it possible with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280015/first-lowercase-the-text-then-capitalize-it-is-it-possible-with-css)

Comment: This worked!!!

.lowercase {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}

.capitalize::first-line {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}