# Javascript: Capitalizing the beginning of every word.

Tags: javascript

The function here's suppose to capitalize the beginning of every word. I know there are other simpler solutions out there, but I'm a little stubborn with why this one isn't working properly. Its tacking an "undefined" after my return every time.

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 

  var c = str[0].charCodeAt(0);
  var letter;
  var result = "";

  if( (c >= "a".charCodeAt(0) && c <="z".charCodeAt(0)) || (c >= "A".charCodeAt(0) && c <="Z".charCodeAt(0)))
  {
    result = str[0].toUpperCase()
  }
  else
  {
    result += str[i];
  }

  for(var i=1; i<=str.length; i++)
  {
        if(str[i-1] == " ")
        {
            letter = str[i].toUpperCase()
            result += letter;
        }
        else
        {
            result += str[i];
        }
  }
       return result; 
}
```

Comment: Related: [Capitalize words in string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2332811/464709).

Comment: `i<=str.length` should be `i<str.length` Your loop is iterating beyond the last index.

Comment: Your initial `if` is unnecessary.

Comment: you have str[i] outside the for .. i loop.

Comment: You bet there are simpler solutions :-), like this one, using just CSS: text-transform: capitalize; But sticking with js, @Crazy Train is right, you're getting over the last index, you should change your condition to 'i < str.length'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

`for(var i = 1; i <= str.length; i++)`

to

`for(var i = 1; i < str.length; i++)`

it will work as you expect. As it stands you are indexing into the string one extra time which will return undefined.

Also the first if/else statement can be ditched altogether. The else statement would be a syntax error anyway with `i is undefined`