# Make chart title as capitalize

Tags: jsp, jfreechart

How to make the title first letter as capital and rest of them are in lower case and make the font as italc

```
String snameTitle=request.getParameter("name");
snameTitle=name.replace("_"," ");

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Reflectance Graph for "+snameTitle,"Wavelength(nm)","Reflectance(%)",xyDataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false,false);
```

Any one sugesst me to make the titleof jfree chart like this *Hyptis suavalovens*

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript function like  this:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
};
```

**Usage:**

```
var name = 'andi sholihin';

var name_caps = name.capitalize();

alert(name_caps);
```

**Output :**

```
Andi Sholihin
```

More Info : [Capitalize words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string)