# How do you capitalize the first letter in a string?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I am disappointed that the below code doesn't work. It is still a lowercase "i". I was trying to capitalize every letter in the string (hence the for loop) but I wanted to stop and address what was going wrong.

```
str = 'i ran there';

for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
  if(i===0){
    str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  }
}


console.log(str);
```

Can someone please describe what is going wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string

Comment: Strings are immutable in JavaScript.

Comment: @RaymondChen  like the certainty of BOD? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new string because strings in javascript are immutable:

First get every word separated:

```
var arrayOfstrings = s.split(" ");
```

Then you can treat each string like there own word

Fancy way  :

```
 var capFirstLetter = arrayOfStrings[index].replace(/^./, function (match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
```

Which is just a `regex`. The `/^./` means the first character in the string. And the rest is self explanatory.

Or this way:

```
var s = arrayOfStrings[index];
var s2 = s[0].toUpperCase()+ s.substr(0,1);
```

Or even this really lame way

```
var s = arrayOfStrings[index];
var newS = "";
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
  if(i == 0) newS+= s[0].toUpperCase();
  else newS+= s[i];
}
```

Of course all these can be done in a forloop to cap them all and put back together:

```
 var s = "hello woorld hello world";
 var arrayOfStrings = s.split(" ");
 for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
    arrayOfStrings[i]= arrayOfStrings[i].replace(/^./, function(match) {return match.toUpperCase();}); 
  }
 var s2 = arrayOfStrings.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could do it with something like -

```js
var str = 'i ran there';
var arr = str.split(" ");
var div = document.getElementById("out");
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  // The First letter
  // arr[i] = arr[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substring(1);
  // Every letter
  arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase();
  div.innerHTML += arr[i] + "<br />";
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

As for what is going on in your code, you can't modify the array backing the String (assuming it is an array) like that.

Comment: was the interactive code snippet added to Stack Overflow recently?

Comment: yep, its a new toy :)

Comment: @Wold [Yes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1).

Comment: Is it capable of running anything besides html and JavaScript?

Comment: btw, by the way I read the question, this isn't what he's asking

Comment: @Wold No it isn't, *yet*.

Comment: @KeithNicholas The title asks how to capitalize the first letter of every word. The body asks how to capitalize every word. I've now answered both.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  title asks how to capitalize the first letter in the string,  The body says he was actually intended to capitalize the whole string

Answer (score 0):

whats going wrong here is strings in javascript are immutable.

You can't change them.  What you can do is create a new string with the change.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for index i of a String str. Because str is a String, you cannot use index values to grab certain characters in the string - try `console.log(str[0])` - it will return undefined.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you would need to simply add to a new string after capitalizing each letter. Example:

```
str = 'i ran there';
capStr = ''

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(i === 0) capStr += str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    else capStr += str.charAt(i);
}

console.log(capStr);
```

Comment: This is basically the right answer/what I am looking for.  However, if you add an if/else statement in the for loop (before the capStr line) to check if (i===0) that would be exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!!