# Unable to capitalize the word in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to change the entire word into capital letters. What is wrong with my approach, for individual letters **toUpperCase** is working fine

```
var name = "gates";
for (var i=0; i< name.length; i++){
name[i] = name[i].toUpperCase();
}
name;
```

So the thing is "hello world".toUpperCase() is working fine as expected. Why the looping individual characters in array does not work as expected!. 
**Is this some property in arrays/strings especially in JS**?

As RGraham mentioned the string letters cannot be modified, I don't understand the negative feedback of the community. Even the question seems to be valid.

Comment: use toUpperCase function, Please google before post it on  stackoverflow

Comment: May be I asked the question wrongly, I will update my question

Comment: @ioums hyperlink is not enabled

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capitalize words in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string.charAt(x) or string\[x\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx). Seriously!

Comment: Why would you even want to do it like this

Comment: Im trying to help, and just curius why you want to do it like this. Dont be mad brah

Comment: You can edit the question but you are negative towards the people that are trying to help.

Comment: I am exploring the JS , so "hello world".toUpperCase() worked fine, but done with a loop did not. So got curious and asked. @The_Monster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work, is that accessing a string using the array syntax is **read-only**. As per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> For character access using bracket notation, *attempting to delete or
>   assign a value to these properties will not succeed*. The properties
>   involved are neither writable nor configurable. (See
>   [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information.)

So, `console.log(name[0])` will work, but `name[0] = "G";` will not update the `name` variable.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for!

Comment: @gates You're welcome. Don't be discouraged by the voting and comments on your question. It read absolutely fine to me.

Comment: I must appologize I must have overread the paragraph directly following the code. Revoced my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop through the letters, just do:

```
var name = "gates";
name = name.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

A string is immutable in most languages, meaning, you can't change individual characters, or add something, without ending up with a new one.

```
name = name.toUpperCase();
```

Will give you what you need, but a new, all-caps string is put in the variable 'name'.

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var res = str.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var res = str.toUpperCase();
```

Result:

```
HELLO WORLD!
```