# How to format input value on keyDown()?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to force the input value of a text field to comply with a specific format. It needs to be capitalized and with no numbers allowed.

I would like this event to fire on `onKeydown()`.

Examples:

```
Lionel MESSI => Lionel Messi
LiONEL MesSI => Lionel Messi

Neymar JR => Neymar Jr
Neymar 22 JR => Neymar Jr

Franck D'HONNEUR => Franck D'Honneur

Kevin PEREZ ROBERTO => Kevin Perez Roberto
```

Comment: What do you mean by `force user` ? Do you want to change the text after he entered it ? While he entered it ?

Comment: See the docs... [String - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: @Steffi was my answer of any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple one-liner way of doing this. However, you can make a function which can format the name for you.

Originally taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string), I've modified it slightly to reflect your desired output:

```js
var name1 = "Lionel MESSI";
var name2 = "LiONEL MesSI";
var name3 = "Neymar JR";
var name4 = "Neymar 22 JR";
var name5 = "Franck D'HONNEUR";
var name6 = "Kevin PEREZ ROBERTO";

function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  }).replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
}

console.log(toTitleCase(name1));
console.log(toTitleCase(name2));
console.log(toTitleCase(name3));
console.log(toTitleCase(name4));
console.log(toTitleCase(name5));
console.log(toTitleCase(name6));
```

You may want to check out [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) from the MDN documentation.

---

To get this functionality in on `onKeyDown()`, you can use jQuery like the snippet below. I do advice against `onKeyDown()` though as this creates a weird user experience. Try `onBlur` instead.

```js
function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  }).replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
}

$("#name").on("keydown", function() {
  $(this).val(toTitleCase($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input id="name">
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a little helper function from this question: [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

I wrote a quick script that fires on input blur:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function capitalizeFirstLetterOfEachWord(string) {
        strArr = string.split(' ');
        resArr = [];
        for(i=0;i<strArr.length;i++){
            resArr[i] = strArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArr[i].slice(1);
        }
        return resArr.join(" ");
    }

    $('.forceCapital').blur(function(e) {
        $(this).val(capitalizeFirstLetterOfEachWord($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sa2ox30d/2/

Comment: This only capitalizes the first letter.

Comment: and why not to use css?

Comment: @Gayane see my edit. CSS can't parse strings or listen for the onBlur event.