# Capitalize array element Javascript Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way for us to perform UCWords just like [this](https://blog.smalldo.gs/2014/06/easily-add-phps-ucwords-ucfirst-to-javascript/) function into all elements of an array? I would prefer not to do a forloop into this. But if there are better and more elegant approach would appreciate any suggestion. I'm trying to implement this in NodeJs but I can't find the equivalent functionality of UCWord of PHP in JS/Node

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
String.prototype.toUpperCaseWords = function() {
    return this.replace(/\w+/g, a => { 
        return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    })
}

let myArray = ['some string', 'another string']
let mappedArray = myArray.map(element => element.toUpperCaseWords())
console.log(mappedArray)
```

Alternative without **prototype**

```js
let myArray = ['some string', 'another string']
let mappedArray = myArray.map(element => {
    return element.replace(/\w+/g, a => { 
        return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    })
})
console.log(mappedArray)
```

Comment: receiving an error toUpperCaseWords() is not a function

Comment: You still have to **prototype** the function as shown in your link. I'll update my answer with the code aswell.

Comment: @MadzQuestioning I added an example without prototyping `toUpperCaseWords`