# Replace lowercase character in href with uppercase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

I have a web page that generates links for keywords. The links get generated on the web page like so:

```
https://www.example.com/?keywords=energy
https://www.example.com/?keywords=wind%20power
```

I'd like to change it so that the first character after the `=` (and the `%20` when applicable) is uppercase:

```
https://www.example.com/?keywords=Energy
https://www.example.com/?keywords=Wind%20Power
```

Currently, I have been changing them to uppercase on a per keyword basis:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('energy', 'Energy');
    });

    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('wind%20power', 'Wind%20Power');
    });
});
```

Is there a way to do this, but with any string? I've tried several regular expressions but cannot seem to find a regex for replacing the first character after the equals sign with its uppercase equivalent using javascript. For example I tried this (https://regex101.com/r/ybQbaE/1/), and then tried to dump it into my script on the page:

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace(\=.,\U$0);
    });
});`
```

Of course it didn't work because it's for PHP, but when I click on the ECMAscript Flavor on the regex tester it just replaces the equals sign and the first character after it with `\U$0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are your only cases you can solve it with a simple one liner:

```
url="https://www.example.com/?keywords=wind%20power%20earth%20fire"
url.replace(/(=\w)|(\s\w)|(%20\w)/g,val=>val.toUpperCase())
```

For more information regarding [Regexp patterns visit this.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)
For more on the javascript replace function visit [the Replace MSDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you! And thanks for the links as well. I am definitely learning a lot about regular expressions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can match an `=`, then use another replacer function inside which replaces contiguous alphabetical characters with their upper-case version:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace(
        /=(.+)/g,
        (_, keywords) => '=' + keywords.replace(
            /([a-z])([a-z]*)/gi,
            (_, initial, rest) => initial.toUpperCase() + rest.toLowerCase()
        )
    );
});
```

```js
$('a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace(
        /=(.+)/g,
        (_, keywords) => '=' + keywords.replace(
            /([a-z])([a-z]*)/gi,
            (_, initial, rest) => initial.toUpperCase() + rest.toLowerCase()
        )
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.example.com/?keywords=energy">a</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/?keywords=wind%20power">a</a>
```

Comment: What about using post 2010 technology?

Comment: What do you mean? `.replace` works just fine, and the implicit return of arrow functions (an ES2015 feature) is really nice. I guess you could make the `'=' + keywords.replace` into a template literal, but that'd be too hard to read IMO

Comment: well, I left an answer about the usage of the built-in URL() parser. Maybe not the best way idk, but at least it's readable and even memorizable (As I did there, by head).

Answer (score 0):

No need to get fancy, use the `URL()` constructor!

```js
let url = new URL("https://www.example.com/?keywords=wind%20power%20earth%20fire");

let params = url.searchParams.get('keywords')
console.log(params)

params.split(" ").forEach( (e) => {
    console.log(
      e[0].toUpperCase() + e.substring(1)
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Hey, that's pretty cool, I like the URL interface. Though note that OP needs to *change* the href, not just *log* the changed words.

Comment: Sure, need concatenation, should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Usually regex should be the last step, when there are no specific encoders/decoders left to help. (like in this case, *decodeURIComponent* or the *URL* constructor)

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a=>{
    var url = new URL(a.href);
    var keywords = url.searchParams.get('keywords')
    if( keywords ){
      //Capitalize thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592235/1683017
      keywords = keywords.replace(/(?:^|\s|["'([{])+\S/g, m => m.toUpperCase())
      url.searchParams.set('keywords', keywords )
      a.href = url.href;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler conceptually (for me anyway):

```
url.replace(/=.*/, k => k.replace(/[a-z]+/g, s => s.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: That just replaces Everything after the '=' sign to upper case. I believe the op wanted to capitalize only the first letter after the '=' sign and also the first one after every space.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match = or %20, you'll just want to modify your regex to include the %20 as an option, make sure you have the global flag set, and then pass a function to your replace function to uppercase the parts of the string that match.

```js
let url = "https://www.example.com/?keywords=wind%20power%20earth%20fire";

let regex = /(?<=\=|%20)(.)/g;
url = url.replace(regex, function (match, capture) {
    return capture.toUpperCase();
})

console.log(url)
```